# Don't allow to show all popups immediately just one popup must be opened onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b0qb37f4/6/

You can see my code there. My problem is this: I have 4 links and clicking each of them opens corresponding popup, but I mustn't allow to show a lot of popups immediately just one popup must be opened, so clicking on one of the link must open it's popup but when user click on other clicks that click event should be disabled.

In my code I've used `.off('click')` but after closing popup the links are still disabled. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: ok, I'm sorry will read it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simpler solution:

Change your code to the following one and add "popup" class to your divs:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.fp").click(function(){
        $(".popup").hide();
        $("div.fp").fadeIn();        
    });

    $("a.sp").click(function(){
        $(".popup").hide();
        $("div.sp").fadeIn();        
    });

    $("a.tp").click(function(){
        $(".popup").hide();
        $("div.tp").fadeIn();        
    });

    $("a.ftp").click(function(){
        $(".popup").hide();
        $("div.ftp").fadeIn();        
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="fp">First popup | </a>
<a class="sp">Second popup | </a>
<a class="tp">Third popup | </a>
<a class="ftp">Fourth popup</a>
<div class="popup fp">Hi, this is first popup content.<span>X</span></div>
<div class="popup sp">Hi, this is second popup content.<span>X</span></div>
<div class="popup tp">Hi, this is third popup content.<span>X</span></div>
<div class="popup ftp">Hi, this is fourth popup content.<span>X</span></div>
```

Edit for the latest question:

You can suppress the function when you check if a popup is currently visible with this pseudo selector:

```
$("a.fp").click(function(){
    if($('.popup:visible').length > 0)
        return; // do nothing

    $(".popup").hide();
    $("div.fp").fadeIn();        
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's really useful but there is one thing when I open one popup, and then click on other links to open other popups just want to disable the rest clicks what you think about this?

Comment: Check out my last edit below the html code.

Comment: I update fiddle as you suggest: http://jsfiddle.net/2j1obh92/2/ but no success popups aren't shown at all

Comment: My fault. I missed checking the length of selected elements. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

The `.off('click')` function in your code removes the click event from an element. That's why the links get disabled. Adding and removing event listeners `.on() .off()` is complicated. It's easier to make sure that everytime you open a new popup the old popup gets closed. Adding a `.popup` class would be the first step. I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2j1obh92/

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("a.fp").click(function(){
        jQuery(".popup").hide();
        jQuery(".first").fadeIn();
    });

    jQuery("a.sp").on('click', function(){
        jQuery(".popup").hide();
        jQuery(".second").fadeIn();
    });

    jQuery("a.tp").on('click', function(){
        jQuery(".popup").hide();
        jQuery(".third").fadeIn();
    });

    jQuery("a.ftp").on('click', function(){
        jQuery(".popup").hide();
        jQuery(".fourth").fadeIn();
    });

    // Hide the popup if the X gets clicked
    jQuery(".popup span").on('click', function(){
        jQuery(".popup").hide();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="fp">First popup | </a>
<a class="sp">Second popup | </a>
<a class="tp">Third popup | </a>
<a class="ftp">Fourth popup</a>
<div class="popup fp">Hi, this is first popup content.<span>X</span></div>
<div class="popup sp">Hi, this is second popup content.<span>X</span></div>
<div class="popup tp">Hi, this is third popup content.<span>X</span></div>
<div class="popup ftp">Hi, this is fourth popup content.<span>X</span></div>
```